# Performing Bit modification on Floating point numbers in Matlab

Tags: matlab, binary, floating-point, bit-manipulation

I'm working in Matlab using Non-negative Matrix factorization to decompose a matrix into two factors. Using this I get from A two double precision floating point matrices, B and C.

sample results are

```
B(1,1) = 0.118
C(1,1) = 112.035
```

I am now trying to modify specific bits within these values but using the bitset function on either values I get an error because bitset requires unsigned integers.

I have also tried using dec2bin function, which I assumed would convert decimals to binary but it returns '0' for B(1,1).

Does anyone know of any way to deal with floats at bit level without losing precision?

Comment: out of sheer curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Its a steganography project using NNMF for added security. Its a university project but I'm really struggling using Matlab

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should look into the `typecast` and `bitset` functions. (Doc [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitset.html) respectively). That lets you do stuff like

```
xb = typecast( 1.0, 'uint64' );
xb = bitset( xb, 10, 1 );
typecast( xb, 'double' );
```

Comment: This method worked to convert the double to a value bitset could work with however when i convert it back instead of getting 0.118 I get 1.000

Comment: Did you try "bitset(typecast(B(1,1), 'uint64'),...)" ? Also, "format hex" shows you the underlying data values in hex...

Answer (score 0):

The num2hex and hex2num functions are your friends. (Though not necessarily very good friends; hexadecimal strings aren't the best imaginable form for working on binary floating-point numbers. You could split them into, say, 8-nybble chunks and convert each to an integer.)

From the MATLAB docs:

```
num2hex([1 0 0.1 -pi Inf NaN])
```

returns

```
ans =

3ff0000000000000
0000000000000000
3fb999999999999a
c00921fb54442d18
7ff0000000000000
fff8000000000000
```

and

```
num2hex(single([1 0 0.1 -pi Inf NaN]))
```

returns

```
ans =

3f800000
00000000
3dcccccd
c0490fdb
7f800000
ffc00000
```

Comment: typecast is preferable to num2hex. (Not sure when it was introduced)

Comment: Ooo, I didn't know about typecast. I completely agree: better than num2hex and hex2num. Thanks.